# nodejs pem generated openssl self signed certificate generation for intranet CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: node.js, express, pem

I am using the module "pem" for nodejs && express to generate openssl self signed certificates for a demo webserver run over a local intranet.

The issue I am having is that when I attempt to load pages off the webserver I am receiving the error: "The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite."

How would I be able to utilize pem ( or other ) in a way to allow me run my webserver over https via my intranet?

I am running/testing this on a ubtuntu machine and also testing on a windows machine. Both are generating the same error - the accessible machine over the intranet would be from the linux box. I am using nodejs 10 and tested on firefox, chrome, edge and safari

```
  ...

  pem.createCertificate({ days: 365, selfSigned: true }, this.start);

  ...

  start(err, keys) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }

    let server = https.createServer(app,
      { key: keys.serviceKey, cert: keys.certificate });

    server.listen(port,
      () => console.log(`API/NG running on https://localhost:${port}`)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/web_server/server.js) of the pem module, the order of arguments is in reverse order, like follows:

```
var serverOptions = {
        key: keys.serviceKey,
        cert: keys.certificate
    };

    var app = express();
    var server = https.createServer(serverOptions, app);
```